# Direct db connection per http request vs connection pooling- what is the difference

Tags: java, database, postgresql, connection-pooling, sharding

Let's say I am storing data of `Person(id, country_id, name)`. And let's say user just sent the id and country_id and we send back the name.

Now I have one db and 2 webserver and each webserver keeps a connection pool (e.g. c3p0) of 20 connection.

That means db is maintaining 40 connections and each webserver is maintaining 20 connections.

Analyzing the above system we can see that we used connection pool because people say "creating db connection is expensive"

This all make sense

---

Now let's say I shard table data on `country_id`, so now there may be 200 db, also assuming our app is popular now and we need to have 50 webserver.
Now the above strategy of connection pooling fails as if each webserver is keeping 20 connections in the pool for each db.
that means each webserver will have 20*200 db = 4000 connection
and each db will have 50 web server *20 = 1000 connection.

This doesn't sound good, so I got the question that why use connection pooling what is the overhead of creating 1 connection per web request?

So I run a test where I saw that `DriverManager.getConnection()` takes a average of 20 ms on localhost.

20 ms extra per request is not a game killer

**Question1:** Is there any other downside of using 1 connection per web request ?

**Question2:** People all over internet say "db connection is expensive". What are the different expenses?

---

PS: I also see pinterest doing same https://medium.com/@Pinterest_Engineering/sharding-pinterest-how-we-scaled-our-mysql-fleet-3f341e96ca6f

Comment: There are technologies to enhance pooling (ie. Java Servlets contexts on the same server can share a connection pool) and sharding (ie. [`pgpool`](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page))

Comment: Did you test how long that takes if you have to cope with 10000 page impressions per second on the front end? i.e. 10000 calls to `getConnection()` per second over a network connection?

Answer (score 6):

Other than Connection creation & Connection close cycle being a time consuming task ( i.e. being costly ) , pooling is also done to control the number of simultaneous open connections to your database since there is a limit on number of simultaneous connections that a db server can handle. When you do , one connection per request , you loose that control and your application is always at risk of crashing at peak load.

Secondly, you would unnecessarily tie your web server capacity with your database capacity and target is also to treat db connection management not as a developer concern but an infrastructure concern. Would you like to give control to open a database connection for production application to developer as per his/her code?

In traditional monolithic application servers like Weblogic, JBoss, WebSphere etc, Its sys admin who will create a connection pool as per db serer capacity and pass on JNDI name to developers to use to.Developer's job is to only get connection using that JNDI.

Next comes if database is shared among various independent applications then pooling lets you know as what you are giving out to which application. Some apps might be more data intensive and some might not be that intensive.

Traditional problem of resource leak i.e when developers forget to cleanly close their connection is also taken care of with pooling.

All in all - idea behind pooling is to let developers be concerned only about using a connection and do their job and not being worried about opening and closing it. If a connection is not being used for X minutes, it will be returned to pool per configuration.

Comment: So if we keep a max connection constrain so that after max connection the request get queued.. Plus framework handle the connection creation.. Then does above strategy make sense?

Comment: Hows that different than pooling offered by existing tools?

Comment: We are not maintain the connection we close the connection as soon as work is over.... We don't want to keep 200 db*20 connection =4000 live from each Webserver right"... Thought?

Comment: I think, you can utilize a setting in pool provider where connection gets closed if idle for x minutes.Its part & parcel of pool clean up process. You can set initial & minimum required connections to a low limit.All in all - I think, your requirement can be achieved by configuring the pool properly.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a busy web site and every request to the database opens and closes a connection, you are dead in the water.

The 20ms you measured are for a `localhost` connection. I don't think that all your 50 web servers will be on `localhost`...

Apart from the time it takes to establish and close a database connection, it also uses resources on the database server. This is mostly the CPU, but there could also be contention on kernel data structures.

Also, if you allow several thousand connections, there is nothing that keeps them from all gettings busy at the same time, in which case your database server will be overloaded and unresponsive unless it has several thousand cores (and even then you'd be limited by lock contention).

Your solution is an external connection pool like pgBouncer.